# list match (last N character match)

Tags: erlang, match

I am writing hg(mercurial)'s client now. For tags commands, the reponse is as follows:

> <<"adding a\na\ncommitted changeset
>   0:44108598f0ec643e7d90e9f18a2b6740401a510a\ntip
>   1:ce4daf41b6ae\nmy tags
>   0:44108598f0ec\ntest tag                          0:44108598f0ec
>   local\n">>.

The python's related code is as follows:

```
    t = []
    for line in out.splitlines():
        taglocal = line.endswith(' local')
        if taglocal:
            line = line[:-6]
        name, rev = line.rsplit(' ', 1)
        rev, node = rev.split(':')
        t.append((name.rstrip(), int(rev), node, taglocal))
    return t
```

I have to check everyline for "local" postfix, but the compiler give syntax error. How to write correctly and elegant.
error message:

```
src/emercurial_client.erl:763: illegal pattern
```

Code

```
process_tags(List)->
    process_tags(List,[]).

process_tags([],Result)->
    lists:reverse(Result);

process_tags([Line|Rest],Result) ->
    B = binary_to_list(Line),
    A = process_tags_line(B),
    process_tags(Rest,[A|Result]).

process_tags_line(New_list ++"local")->   %%<-----error here
process_tags_line(New_list);

process_tags_line(New_list)->
    %% case List of
    %%     Data ++ " local" ->   %%<-----also match error
    %%         New_list = Data;
    %%     _ ->
    %%         New_list = List
    %% end,
    [Name,Part2] = string:tokens(Data," "),
    [Rev,Node] = string:tokens(Part2,":"),
    {trim(Name),love_misc:to_integer(Rev),
     node,New_list}.
```

After modification, it is follows:

```
process_tags(List)->
    List_b = binary:split(List,<<$\n>>,[global]),
    Result = process_tags(List_b,[]),
    %% error_logger:info_report([client_process_tags,Result]),
    Result.

process_tags([],Result)->
    lists:reverse(Result);

process_tags([<<>>],Result)->
    lists:reverse(Result);

process_tags([Line|Rest],Result) ->
    B = binary_to_list(Line),
    A = process_tags_line(B),
    process_tags(Rest,[A|Result]).

process_tags_line(List) -> 
    %% error_logger:info_report([client_tags_line_1,List]),
    case lists:suffix(" local",List) of
        true ->
            New_list = lists:sublist(List,1,length(List)-7);
        _ ->
            New_list = List
    end,
    {Name,Part2} = rsplit(New_list,$\s),
    {Rev,Node} = 
        rsplit(Part2,$:),
    Rev_a =  string:substr(Rev,1,length(Rev)-1),
    {love_misc:trim(Name),love_misc:to_integer(Rev_a),Node,New_list}.

rsplit(A,Char)->
    Index = string:rchr(A,Char),
    lists:split(Index,A).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed in documentation, you can [match only prefixes in similar way](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id76253) (which in fact just a syntactic sugar).

I'd suggest you to use function [`lists:suffix`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#suffix-2)

So, you can rewrite your code in such way:

```
New_list = 
    case lists:suffix(" local", List) of
        true ->
            Data;
        false ->
            List
    end
```

Note, that `case` expressions **returns values**, so you can bind variable `New_List` only once - with **result** of `case` expression, instead of binding in each branch of `case` expression

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot use this pattern matching because of the underlying structure of a list ([A|[B|[....|[]...]]).

The reverse works so you can do something like

```
process_tags_line(List) ->
    process_tags_line_1(lists:reverse(List)).
process_tags_line1(" lacol"++L) -> process_tags_line1(L);
process_tags_line1(L) ->
    New_list = lists:reverse(L),
    [Name,Part2] = string:tokens(Data," "),
    [Rev,Node] = string:tokens(Part2,":"),
    {trim(Name),love_misc:to_integer(Rev),node,New_list}.
```

But the simplest thing may be to use lists:suffix(L1,L2)...